# Make the button active if the data is changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to track changes if the value of the input field is already there. Probably it will be necessary to make the button active

```
class NameForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: ''};

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Name:
          <input type="text" value="John" />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="send" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't define value like `value="John"` because it's not dynamic. you won't be able to change. so better to define your default value in state like this- `this.state = {name: 'John'}`.

```
class NameForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {name: 'John', isChanged: false };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({name: event.target.value, isChanged: true});
  }
  handleSubmit=e=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state)
  }
  render() {
    const {name, isChanged} = this.state;
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Name:
          <input type="text" value={name} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
        </label>
        { isChanged && <input type="submit" value="send" /> }
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Hide submit button after submission-https://codesandbox.io/s/form-t00t4

Edit: Keeping the state of whether input is touched or not in **ischanged**.

Comment: thanks a lot. What will the function look like: if the data has changed, then display the button?

Comment: @stiv it depends on requirement if you want to hide after submission then hide that

Comment: @stiv check live demo for hiding submit button. if answer is helpful for you please accept/vote for this.

Comment: I’ll try to explain better: 1) initially there is no button 2) when the data is entered the button is displayed

Comment: @stiv while handling the change of input in handleChange as specified now keep a state which denotes whether input is not been touched. I have updated the code. Please check. Kept another state variable ischanged for knowing whether input was ever updated.

Comment: No problem @VahidAkhtar 

Also You can hide the button when there's nothing in the input by simply checking in the handleChange method whether the input has any value or empty string, if thats so then just make isChanged false.